# How to attract correct answers to a difficult question?

Tags: discussion

My colleague ran into a kind of difficult problem, that he couldn't solve, so he asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974608/androids-xmlpullparser-equivalent-for-ios-swift).

Since the question hasn't received enough attraction and my colleague is kinda new to the site, I've decided to invest some of my reputation to attract more viewers and possible answers.

I hoped that it'd have a higher impact, but the question has still quite poor views and answers, but I guess that's because of the field of the questions. Since I'm from a different background I can't really tell that.

Now, I feel kind of clueless what I can do.

1. I've checked the question if there could be anything wrong with it, but couldn't quit find something.
2. I've awarded an bounty to create more attention to the question.

There are only two answers to the question right now, but both are kind of unsatisfactory.

The first one that has a few upvotes, compares two libraries about performance and explains some `basic usage` of the one that he's giving a recommendation for.

As clearly stated in the question, this all has been tried before. I don't really now if the questions has been read at all. At this point, this answer would be awarded the bounty automatically and I do not want this. Not because he hasn't put effort into the answer, but because the answer **doesn't fit** the question asked.

I have flagged the answer as `not as answer`

> because but it does not attempt to answer the question

in my opinion and I got an dispute on that, but I think it's okay. That's not really my problem here.

The second answer seemed quite good, but sadly the user who has answered doesn't reply anymore - nothing we can do here, since this is the choice of the user.

What could I possible do to attract more attention to the question for the sake of **correct answer or at least answers that fit the questions asked**.

Comment: One would hope SO is all about having correct answers for the question asked... The only thing you can do is to have a crystal clear question that focuses on the actual problem. I made an edit to the question trying to go in this direction, feel free to edit it some more (avoid asking for tools or "the equivalent of X in language Y", focus on the task)

Comment: Correct is maybe the wrong term, it's just frustrating to see that there are answers that doesn't fit the question asked and still get upvoted. Thank you for the edit, I like it.

Comment: @KhorneHoly the problem there is more that people don't downvote, not that incorrect answers are posted. You can't stop that from happening, but then the voting system should "solve" the problem. Except that it doesn't always.